# Filing taxes as a former inmate

Tags: united-states, income-tax

My son has been in and out of prison since 2006. He will be out in October of this year again. He has worked in some of the prisons he been to. Can he file taxes for the times he has been in prison, if so how far back can he file and what forms will he need

---

We live in the USA in Buffalo NY, No they did not he is still in prison and wont be out until late in the year. He wants to know what forms to get from the jail before he is released. Thank You

Comment: Did the prisons send him a 1099 or W2?  If not, I don't think there's any income for him to pay tax on.

Comment: I highly doubt that he got paid enough that he needs to file taxes. I would think that he didn't have any taxes withheld so the benefit is also in question. Neither of those should prevent you from filing though.

Answer (score 4):

He can file his taxes as many years back as he pleases to.  And further, he owes ***all*** those back taxes, if taxes are owed.

However, if he is owed a refund, IRS will not give a refund if your taxes are filed more than 3 years after the due date.  They let you have holidays and weekends.

He will need Form 1099 or Form W-2 for each year that he had income.